# display latest additions sqlalchemy

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I'm new to Stack Overflow and programming in general.

I'm trying to get a handle on `SQLAlchemy` in `Python`.  I'm attempting to pull the last 5 entries (most recently added) from a database, but can't quite figure out where I'm going wrong.  Any advice is greatly appreciated

```
Additions = session.query(SportsItems).order_by(asc('updated desc')).limit(5)
```

Obviously looking to query the `SportsItems` database and pull the last 5 items added, but no luck thus far

I have the rest of the session code working properly as I'm able to display other queries as intended, just can't figure out this particular query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should **order the modification date in descending order**:

```
session.query(SportsItems).order_by(SportsItems.updated.desc()).limit(5).all()
```

You thus call `desc()` on the column of the table.

Comment: Hmmm says the database doesn't have the attribute "updated"  AttributeError: type object 'SportsItems' has no attribute 'update'

Comment: @KJJohnson: how did you wrote the column in the `SportsItem` table?

Comment: SportsItems table has name, description, price and sport.  Would I need another column for updated to log when it is added?

Comment: @KJJohnson: but based on your question, the table has an `updated` column. That is not in the table description in Python/SQLAlchemy?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion.  That 'updated desc' portion I was attempting to add manually.  No, there is no updated column in the table

Comment: @KJJohnson: but how can you sort a table based on something that does not exist. Most databases do not store when a row was modified, nor do they order results (guaranteed) by modification date. In case you need that, you probably have to add a column `updated` somehow that keeps track of it

Comment: Ok thanks, I was thinking it somehow tracked when the last additions were made to the database.  I'll go about creating an updated column.  Appreciate the help and advice